# Vertical spacing between chapters in a tocloft List of Equations

Tags: spacing, tocloft

I have a List of Equations in my thesis, built using tocloft. The thing that's bothering me is that, in the List of Figures and List of Tables, there's vertical space where one chapter's figures/tables end and the next chapters' begins. Example:

[image: Example List of Tables, including space between chapters]

My equations don't have this:

[image]

I've tried manipulating the new List of Equations with the \@cftasnum command, which I think will give me the result I need (that or \@cftasnumb) but I can't get the syntax right and my \renewcommand is invalid.

Tocloft definition code sample (with my hatchet-job redefinition commented out at the end):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    % use report class, set font size
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} % specify A4 paper

\usepackage{tocloft}    % used for list of equations - TAG ALL EQUATIONS WITH \myequations command
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}  % width of equation number in List of Equations

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}
\listofmyequations

\chapter{Start}
Start of chapter

\begin{equation}
\Delta N_{eff} = \frac{\Delta V_{FB} C_{ox}}{q}
\label{eqnNotHyst}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Oxide-trapped Charge and Hysteresis Voltage}

Some paragraph text

\begin{equation}
\psi_s(V_G)= \int_{V_{G1}}^{V_{G2}}(1-\frac{C_{lf}(V_G)}{C_{ox}})dV_G + \Delta
\label{eqnlitBerglund1}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Classical Berglund Integral}

\chapter{Middle}
Start of chapter

\begin{equation}
D_{it} (V_G)=\frac{C_{ox}}{q^2} \left(\frac{C_{lf}/C_{ox}}{1-C_{lf}/C_{ox}}-\frac{C_{hf}/C_{ox}}{1-C_{hf}/C_{ox}}\right)
\label{eqnhighlowDit}
\end{equation}
\myequations{High-low D$_{it}$}

Some paragraph text

\begin{equation}
\psi_s(V_G)= \int_{V_{G1}}^{V_{G2}}(1-\frac{C_{lf}(V_G)}{C_{ox}})dV_G + \Delta
\label{eqnhighlowpsi}
\end{equation}
\myequations{High-low $\psi$}

Some more paragraph text

\begin{equation}
D_{it}(\psi_s) = \frac{C_{ox}}{q} [\frac{d\psi_s}{dV_G}^{-1}-1]-C_s(\psi_s)
\label{eqntermanDit}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Terman Method for D$_{it}$}

\chapter{End}
Some text

\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{h}{m^*v_{th}}
\label{eqndeBroglie}
\end{equation}
\myequations{de Broglie wavelength of an electron/hole}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are using the `memoir` then you don't need `tocloft` as it is built in. With `memoir` the way to get the spaces in a new listof is via: `\addtodef{\insertchapterspace}{}{\addtocontents{equ}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}`. See the manual for details.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, now I've tested it.  I suppose I could have created my own MWE, but I would not have used tocloft.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    % use report class, set font size
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} % specify A4 paper

\usepackage{tocloft}    % used for list of equations - TAG ALL EQUATIONS WITH \myequations command
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}  % width of equation number in List of Equations

\let\oldchapter=\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\addtocontents{equ}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \oldchapter}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}
\listofmyequations

\chapter{Start}
Start of chapter

\begin{equation}
\Delta N_{eff} = \frac{\Delta V_{FB} C_{ox}}{q}
\label{eqnNotHyst}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Oxide-trapped Charge and Hysteresis Voltage}

Some paragraph text

\begin{equation}
\psi_s(V_G)= \int_{V_{G1}}^{V_{G2}}(1-\frac{C_{lf}(V_G)}{C_{ox}})dV_G + \Delta
\label{eqnlitBerglund1}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Classical Berglund Integral}

\chapter{Middle}
Start of chapter

\begin{equation}
D_{it} (V_G)=\frac{C_{ox}}{q^2} \left(\frac{C_{lf}/C_{ox}}{1-C_{lf}/C_{ox}}-\frac{C_{hf}/C_{ox}}{1-C_{hf}/C_{ox}}\right)
\label{eqnhighlowDit}
\end{equation}
\myequations{High-low D$_{it}$}

Some paragraph text

\begin{equation}
\psi_s(V_G)= \int_{V_{G1}}^{V_{G2}}(1-\frac{C_{lf}(V_G)}{C_{ox}})dV_G + \Delta
\label{eqnhighlowpsi}
\end{equation}
\myequations{High-low $\psi$}

Some more paragraph text

\begin{equation}
D_{it}(\psi_s) = \frac{C_{ox}}{q} [\frac{d\psi_s}{dV_G}^{-1}-1]-C_s(\psi_s)
\label{eqntermanDit}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Terman Method for D$_{it}$}

\chapter{End}
Some text

\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{h}{m^*v_{th}}
\label{eqndeBroglie}
\end{equation}
\myequations{de Broglie wavelength of an electron/hole}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just tried it: it seems to have completely overwritten \chapter and (obviously) won't build

Comment: Anyway, you need to add the \addtocontents every time you add a chapter.  Without a MWE, I can only guess.

Comment: @OVavasour: Instead of complaining you could have helped yourself by adding a compilable document instead of fragments only. John tried to help you!

Comment: I've updated the question with a full, compilable example. Apologies, I'm relatively new and thought it would be just a simple syntax fix. Lesson learned